# Inno Setup uses installation path of another installer

Tags: javafx, inno-setup

I made two self contained JavaFX applications with JavaFX (Windows). So I have two installers of different applications. The problem is if I install the application A and then install the application B, the last installed application will use the path installation of application A. There is no configuration issue that was generated in the installer because if I reverse the order, the application B is installed and the application A is in the place of B.

Ex: AppA Application: Local `C:\Users\some user\AppData\Local\AppA` was installed and shortly thereafter I install the B application that should be in AppB folder, but instead is installed in AppA. If I reverse the installation order, the AppA will be at AppB folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because both your installers have the same `AppId`. If you do not set the `AppId`, value of `AppName` is used.

The `AppId` must be unique.

See https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid

In JavaFX the `AppId` is set using `id` attribute of [`<fx:application>` tag](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIAGCAFH).

Comment: @caju You are welcome. I've added info on the `fx:application` to my answer.